# Correct usage of abstract case class

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to model a scenario where I'm trying to achieve immutability rather than modifying instance variables. The way I'm achieving this is as below.

```
case class TSS(k:Int, v:Int)
case class Combiner(a:Int,b:Int, tss: TSS) {
    def func1():Option[TSS] = None
    def func2():Option[TSS] = None
    
    def modifyState(externalV: Int): Combiner = {
      Combiner(this.a + 1, this.b+1, func1())
    }

}


case class OneCombiner extends Combiner {
    override def func1():Option[TSS] = SOME_MODIFIED_TSS
    override def func2():Option[TSS] = SOME_MODIFIED_TSS
}

case class TwoCombiner extends Combiner {
    override def func1():Option[TSS] = SOME_MODIFIED_TSS
    override def func2():Option[TSS] = SOME_MODIFIED_TSS
}
```

Now when I'm trying to use the `OneCombiner` and `TwoCombiner` as below they are using the `func1` and `func2` of base class and setting the value of `tss` to `None` rather than using the overridden versions.

For example

```
val a:Combiner = OneCombiner

val anotherCombiner = a.modifyState()
```

In this case `anotherCombiner.tss` is being returned as `None` rather than `SOME_TSS_VALUE`.

What is the correct functional way of modelling such behaviour in Scala ?

I also tried making `Combiner` `abstract case class` but that failed to compile because then I was unable to create the `Combiner` object in `modifyState` method.

Comment: `modifyState` creates a new `Combiner`. It doesn't know about child classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `modifyState` is creating a new `Combiner` rather than the appropriate subclass. This is because it is combining state with abstract behaviour in one class.

The best solution is to make a separate concrete `State` class and have the `Combiner`s as functions that take a `State` and return a new one. This separates the different behaviours from the actual state itself.

```
case class TSS(k: Int, v: Int)
case class State(a: Int, b: Int, tss: TSS) 
trait Combiner {
  def func1(): TSS
  def modifyState(state: State, externalV: Int): State
    = State(state.a + 1, state.b+1, func1())
}

case class OneCombiner() extends Combiner {
  def func1(): TSS = ???
}

case class TwoCombiner() extends Combiner {
  def func1(): TSS = ???
}
```

If you want to retain a single class you need to have a separate constructor for each subclass, and the easiest way to do that is to make `modifyState` virtual and implement it in each subclass. It is not clear how many of the other values need to be exposed in the `trait` so I have put them all in, just in case.

```
case class TSS(k: Int, v: Int)
trait Combiner {
  def a: Int
  def b: Int
  def tss: TSS
  def func1(): Option[TSS]
  def func2(): Option[TSS]
  def modifyState(externalV: Int): Combiner
}

case class OneCombiner(a: Int, b: Int, tss: TSS) extends Combiner {
  override def func1(): Option[TSS] = ???
  override def func2(): Option[TSS] = ???
  def modifyState(externalV: Int): OneCombiner =
    OneCombiner(this.a + 1, this.b + 1, func1().getOrElse(???))
}

case class TwoCombiner(a: Int, b: Int, tss: TSS) extends Combiner {
  override def func1(): Option[TSS] = ???
  override def func2(): Option[TSS] = ???
  def modifyState(externalV: Int): TwoCombiner =
    TwoCombiner(this.a + 1, this.b + 1, func1().getOrElse(???))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one doubt though,  since `modifyState` is same code duplicated in both class is there no way to avoid it ? I have copied the code now in both case classes and it is working, but just wondering if there is any way to avoid code duplication.

Comment: The first version avoids that problem which is why it is preferable. If you use the second version, you could add a helper to do the calculations, but you must have a different method to actually create the new `Combiner` of the appropriate type so there is inevitably some duplication.